# Potential VBA solution for wanting a cell to update its manually inputed contents once data is entered in another cell

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I want data in the cells of column J to copy the data in the cells of column G once data is inputted into column G and not before.

However, prior to this replication taking place I would like to be able to manually update the price in the cells of column J.

See the attached photo for clarity.

Could anyone suggest a solution? I know VBA is a possibility, however, my Excel knowledge is not good enough to write code.

Yellow headings represent no formulas and blue represent formulas.

[Excel_Worksheet_ TRADE LOG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xAqFP.jpg)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
    With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Range("C:C"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, -1).ClearContents
            Else
                With .Offset(0, -1)
                    .NumberFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
                    .Value = Now
                End With
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
    With Target
        If .Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
        If Not Intersect(Range("G:G"), .Cells) Is Nothing Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            If IsEmpty(.Value) Then
                .Offset(0, 12).ClearContents
            Else
                With .Offset(0, 12)
                    .NumberFormat = "dd MMM yyyy"
                    .Value = Now
                End With
            End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Let's first understand what you are trying to do: my guess is you want to freely write values to column J (the count of values will be greater than or equal to the count of the values in column `G`). Initially column `G` is empty. As you add data in column `G`, the value of the current cell will be overwritten with the value in column `J` of the same row. In a nutshell: column `G` can only contain the values from column `J` or `Empty`. Correct me if I'm wrong. I don't think that it could be easily done in `Excel Formula`, but surely could be done with using events in `VBA`.

Comment: Hello, @VBasic2008 thanks for the response. Partially correct, I want to be able to manually update column `J` but as soon as data is put into column `G` then its copies this into column `J`. I agree I don't think the formula is a solution but I cannot write VBA, a bit above my skill level.

Comment: I have understood the difference. I you want to allow a VBA solution, just enable the `vba` tag by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65920466/edit) your post or just confirm in the comments or post and someone else or I will do it for you `:-)`. If not, just ignore the comment `:-(`.

Comment: I have enabled the `VBA` tag and It would be great if you wouldn't mind looking at it for me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A Simple Worksheet Change

- If values in the column range from `G2` to the bottom-most (last) cell of the worksheet, are changed manually or via code, the values of the cells in the corresponding rows in column `J` will be overwritten with the values from column `G`.
- This solution is automated, you don't run anything.

**Sheet Module e.g. `Sheet1` (in parentheses in `Project Explorer` of `Visual Basic Editor`)**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    Const sCell As String = "G2" ' Source First Cell
    Const dCol As Variant = "J" ' Destination Column Id (String or Index) 
    
    Dim irg As Range ' Intersect Range
    Dim cOffset As Long ' Column Offset
    With Range(sCell)
        Set irg = Intersect(.Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), Target)
        If irg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        cOffset = Columns(dCol).Column - .Column
    End With
    
    Dim arg As Range ' Current Area of Intersect Range
    Dim cel As Range ' Current Cell in Current Area of Intersect Range
    For Each arg In irg.Areas
        For Each cel In arg.Cells
            If Not IsError(cel.Value) Then
                cel.Offset(, cOffset).Value = cel.Value
            End If
        Next cel
    Next arg
    
End Sub
```

Comment: That is great, thank you very much for taking the time to do that. I already have some VBA on this worksheet. How would i stitch the two together? Current code is shown back in the question, It would not allow me to copy it into the comments.

Comment: That's kind of out of the scope of the question. But a tip is to try to copy my code to the beginning, in the middle or at the end and test what happens in each of the three cases.